# Changing EdgeInsets of Image and Title of UIButton makes the button looks blur

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, blur, stretch

I am creating a UIButton programatically, when i set the EdgeInsets of button title and image, the button title and image got BLUR. (See reference screenshot)
Why title and image gets blur?
Here is my code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, mainFrame.size.width, mainFrame.size.height);
button.frame = buttonFrame;
[button setTitle:@"Press me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"Pressed" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FNT_ALL_TEXTS size:10]];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageNormal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageSelected] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
UIImage * refimage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageNormal];
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(buttonFrame.size.height*0.5, -refimage.size.width*1.0, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
[button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonFrame.size.height*0.35, 0.0)];
[self addSubview:button];
```

[image: You can see in this image that UIButton image and title are blur]

Answer (score 0):

dear just make sure  that it is content vertical and horizontal alignment for button however u  use image or text in button.

```
UIButton *btn;
btn.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
```

// horizontal Alignment

```
UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft
UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight
UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill
UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter

// Vertical Alignment

UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop
UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill
UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom
UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter
```